# React - Insert material-table Actions in the First and Last Column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Is it possible within `material-table` to insert two separate actions in the first and last columns respectively? I know that there is an `actionsColumnIndex` prop that can be used as such `options={{actionsColumnIndex: -1}}`, but I believe this will add all the actions to the end of the table.

I can't seem to find anything in the [documentation](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions) that specifies how to add actions and specify their individual `actionsColumnIndex` for each, rather than for all the actions (if this is possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is not such a feature, but you can use custom column and create your own action columns.
[image]
Something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import { Save, Delete } from "@material-ui/icons";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";

export default function FreeAction() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Dynamic Actions"
      columns={[
        {
          title: "First Action",
          render: (rowData) => {
            const button = (
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log("Save");
                }}
              >
                <Save />
              </IconButton>
            );
            return button;
          }
        },
        { title: "Name", field: "name" },
        { title: "Surname", field: "surname" },
        { title: "Birth Year", field: "birthYear", type: "numeric" },
        {
          title: "Birth Place",
          field: "birthCity",
          lookup: { 34: "London", 63: "Berlin" }
        },
        {
          title: "Second Action",
          render: (rowData) => {
            const button = (
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log("Save");
                }}
              >
                <Delete />
              </IconButton>
            );
            return button;
          }
        }
      ]}
      data={[
        {
          name: "Jonathan",
          surname: "Livingston",
          birthYear: 1987,
          birthCity: 63
        },
        { name: "Richard", surname: "Bach", birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: "Michael", surname: "Scott", birthYear: 2020, birthCity: 34 },
        { name: "Kevin", surname: "Malone", birthYear: 2020, birthCity: 34 }
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

Have a look at the [code](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/components/m-table-action.js) to add missing features (tooltip for example).

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: hello @Adam what is the code u inserted for the onClick() of icon button?  U called the  functions already in the material table right? how did u do that?